# Communicating with background service

Tags: command-line, process, stdout

I have a process registered as a service running in the background which occasionally logs to `stdout`. It is some linux executable which, if run in the foreground, can receive user commands and respond to them. On the other side, I have a NodeJS project which I would like to use to issue those commands from and to get responses to, while the process is still running in the background.

I can completely control both processes and I can change the way they run if needed, but I wonder if communication like this is even possible, given that the background process might print out few additional log lines between the "request" and "response". If it is possible, what would be the simplest way to achieve this?

Comment: The typical (not mandatory) way to communicate with most headless services is via dbus...but that means your service must include a dbus listener. The user interface and headless-back-end can be different processes, glued together using dbus, and the two can run with different permissions, at different times, and can be written in different languages.  dbus also makes creating the API super-easy for other applications to interact with yours, including output. However, dbus might be a more complex overhaul of your code than you seem to want in a 'simplest' solution.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion! I took a look at dbus a bit, and I have to admit that on the first glance it seems overcomplicated for all this... I might be completely wrong tho... :) Knowing my karma, I'll probably have to learn it and use it in my use case :/ Yes, I mentioned "simplest" way because I thought there could be a way to run my background process in slightly different way, in order to pipe stdin and stdout somehow and being able to use that pipe from some other process... It also might be very obvious that I have very limited knowledge regarding this topic ^^